# How was EU wide minimum wage computed?

Tags: law, european-parliament, minimum-wage

The EU is preparing for rules for [fair minimum wages in the EU](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20211107IPR16808/new-rules-for-fair-minimum-wages-in-the-eu):

> A new draft EU law will ensure a minimum level of wage protection in
> all member states, in order to guarantee decent living standards for
> workers and their families.

Simply eyeballing the [figures from OECD.stats](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIN2AVE#), there is quite a difference between EU states for the minimum relative to average wages of full-time workers. This means that when the minimum wage rule kicks in, states will be impacted differently.

A significant (way more the inflation rate, for example) [increase in minimum wage seem to be a very complicated issue](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/48545/are-there-any-general-rules-that-can-be-used-to-assess-the-consequences-of-a-sig) and it is hard to understand the effects based on the macroeconomic indicators.

I cannot find the rule for minimum wage computation, but [this article](https://www.g4media.ro/video-corina-cretu-salariul-minim-european-se-apropie-de-votul-final-in-parlamentul-european-ce-efecte-va-avea-asupra-salariilor-din-romania.html) (in Romanian, present impact for Romania) suggests that the minimum wage should be 60% of the gross average one. For the specific case of Romania, that would mean a 40% increase that [would be observed by almost half the workers](https://www.romania-insider.com/half-employees-romania-minimum-wage).

I am wondering how the EU Parliament reached the 60% figure. Is this a figure that is country-specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The use of indicators commonly used at international level, such as 60% of the gross median wage and 50% of the gross average wage, can help guide the assessment of minimum wage adequacy in relation to the gross level of wages.

[Source](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/qanda_20_1967)

The EU did not come up with the number itself.